# Using a class property to enable/disable timer

Tags: c#

OK, hopefully I'm not over-complicating this. I know I can just use timer.Enabled = false or timer.Stop() to stop the timer, but I'd like to incorporate a property into my main player class which would control the timer. For instance, if my player had a bool property of "healing," I'd like for when the player's property is set to healing == true, for the timer to begin, and when the player.healing property is changed to healing == false, for the timer to stop. The reason for this is that I'd like my main game loop to continue to run while my player continues to play the game and heal, and when an action is taken in the game, or when the player reaches full health, for the timer to stop.

Currently I have a function that runs each timer tick, and evaluates whether the player is full health or not, and if so, stops the timer. However, I just think being able to flip a bool property from false to true, or vice versa, would be more useful. Any help/thoughts/advice is greatly appreciated!

Comment: When do you set the bool property for the players health? Set the timer to run when you set the bool.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A property setter is just a function, so its pretty easy:

```
private bool healing = false;
public bool Healing
{
     get { return healing; }
     set
     {
         healing = value;
         if (healing)
            timer.Start();
         else
            timer.Stop();
     }
}
```

You want to be careful about side-effects in property setters, because if you don't *actually* want the logic to run *every* time you set the value, you need to go through a seperate function:

```
public bool Healing { get; set; }

public void SetHealingWithTimer(bool status)
{
     Healing = status;
     if (Healing)
         timer.Start();
     else
         timer.Stop();
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I think this will work perfectly, and I did not know you could use a property like that. :)

Is there any real advantage to this method vs. just using timer.Enabled == true/false and having the timer.Elapsed method evaluated whether to stop the timer or not? Just curious.

Comment: @parrotsnest I'm not sure what you mean. As to `timer.Enabled`, I think that `Start/Stop` makes more idiomatic sense. It doesn't really matter though. What are you asking about with the `timer.Elapsed` piece?

Comment: @BradleyDotNET I guess I was looking to do something like objectinstance.heal == true to start a timer and objectinstance.heal == false to stop a timer. In hindsight, I think you are right and I am just looking to over-complicate the process, when timer.Enabled == true/false will work perfectly fine. As I'm new to this site, is there anything I need to do to close this and signal that I have found a solution? Thanks! Cheers all. :)

Answer (score 2):

Cant you do this:

```
private Timer timer;

public bool Healing
{
    get
    {
        return timer.Enabled;
    }
    set
    {
        timer.Enabled=value;
    }
}
```

Comment: Fixed your formatting for you. I would be careful with this, does the timer enabled state *really* represent if the player is healing?

Comment: Thanks for that :) Also I assumed it does.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong with running the timer after player is at full health. Just make to put a restriction on maximum health, i.e.

```
if(health < maxHealth)
{
    healing = true;
    health += healthModifier;
}
else
{       
    healing = false;        
}

//fix health meter, if above maximum
if(health > maxHealth)
{
    health = maxHealth;
}
```

This is also more flexible because you may provide temporary max health boosts later, which will be dependent on another timer (for example).

Comment: True, but you could have reasons for having a "Healing" state (if you have to activate a skill, or if an enemy can stop it).

Comment: @BradleyDotNET: Does it make more sense now?

Comment: Yes, you didn't really need to change anything, it was actually just a comment :). I've upvoted yours and Pheonix's answers as valid alternatives to solve this problem.